# Navigate to Page In Separate assembly using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

So I have two assemblies ProjectA that contains my Application. And ProjectB that contains Pages and other classes.

When attempting to navigate to a page in Project B. Like:

```
// Earlier
RootFrame = new Frame();
Window.Current.Content = RootFrame;

//Relevant Code
RootFrame.Navigate(Type.GetType("ProjectB.MyDisplay,ProjectB"));
```

Doing this gives me the following error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

Other classes can be instantiated. It's just the pages during navigation.

My Goal in this is to have the ability to drop in an assembly and navigate to pages in it. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better approach?

[Update]
This appears to be a limitation in the Framework currently.  See Pix's link below for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you the prism library?
you can load any modules on the fly if needed :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx

This is more a comment than an answer sorry.

EDIT: For your error, I think you should have a look to this thread message.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4efa91ad-fa8f-45f0-9864-c2fd2b24477c/uwpc-accessviolationexception-when-navigating-froma-another-assembly?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Yup. That thread looks like exactly the issue I'm running into.  I haven't used the Prism Library, but I'll take a look.  Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say correct answer. But, it definitely led me in the right direction.  Seems there isn't really an answer currently.  Probably need to add it to the issue list for .NET Core.

Comment: Thx Trent :) Good luck for your project.